# Некорректное отображение надписи на кнопке Java

Tags: java, javafx, button

Надпись на кнопке отображается не полностью (текст на немецком) [image: буква q не влазит (снизу)]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить, если кнопки увеличивать нельзя?

Comment: Уменьшить размер шрифта. Но пользователи с плохим зрением вашим приложением пользоваться перестанут.

Comment: это единственное решение?

Comment: как вариант `button.setPadding( new Insets(  -1 ) );`, но может не помочь

Comment: @ЕгорБарковский у вас есть бумажный стикер и на него надо записать роман "Капитанская дочка". Что делать будете?

Comment: понятно, что можно шрифт уменьшить, просто проблема в том, что на некоторых кнопках такого же размера таким же шрифтом отображается корректно